# iOS - Background Services when app is terminated

Tags: ios, ios-background-mode

Do background mode functions like Background fetch and Location update work if the app is terminated? Or it only works if the app enters background?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, it works (most of the time),** if you set up everything correctly and have the permissions. Your app need's to be launched at least 1 time, so it can subscribe to the updates.

For background fetch, set `UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(3600)` at the `didFinishLaunching` method, implement the `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` method, **and enable the Background Fetch in the Background Modes**.
Pay attention to do it as quickly as possible, and call the completionHandler as soon as possible.

Read more on [Updating Your App with Background App Refresh here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh)

For notification updates, you must also set the `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` property of your `CLLocationManager` object to `true`, and **enable the Location updates in the Background Modes**.

Read more on [Handling Location Events in the Background here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background)

Comment: Yes, it works (most of the time),
- Hi, Does this mean, the app will appear in the App-Switcher. In other words, will the user be able to see the app if he double taps the home button even though he had previously terminated it (removed fromApp-switcher) manually ?

Comment: No, if you kill the app it won't appear in the app switcher but will still receive background updates.

Answer (score 2):

`Background fetch` works like, it allows the app to download the contents when it is background. If the app is terminated and gets some trigger to download content, it will actually wake up by doing silent-launch of the app in the background and download the contents. Please see the Apple description on this below.

> Each of the preceding modes lets the system know that your app should
> be woken up or launched at appropriate times to respond to relevant
> events. For example, an app that begins playing music and then moves
> to the background still needs execution time to fill the audio output
> buffers. Enabling the Audio mode tells the system frameworks that they
> should continue to make the necessary callbacks to the app at
> appropriate intervals. If the app does not select this mode, any audio
> being played or recorded by the app stops when the app moves to the
> background.

Here, preceding modes refer to `Background fetch, Audio and AirPlay, Location updates and other Background modes of the app`.

Please refer [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on Background Execution. See `Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks` for more info on different background modes.

Location update works differently. There are multiple Apple services available to fetch location.

[`Significant Location service`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service): It works in all modes. Foreground, Background and even in terminated mode.

[`Standard Location service`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service): It works only in FG and BG mode. It does not work when the app is in terminated mode.

On more details on Location in BG, please refer [Handling Location Events in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background) document.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The link target of "Apple document" no longer leads to the quoted document.

Answer (score 1):

**Background fetch and Location update work if the app is terminated? Or it only works if the app enters background?**

It depends on which type of `location service` you have used in the project. Refer below analysis of all types of location services.

> [Standard location service:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service?language=objc) If you implemented standard location service then it will work only for `background` and `foreground`
> state.
>
> [Significant location updates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service?language=objc): If you implemented significant location updates then it will work for `background`, `foreground` and
> `terminate` state as well.
>
> [Region Monitoring:](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) If you implemented significant location updates then it will work for `background`, `foreground` and
> `terminate` state as well.
>
> [Visits Location Service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_visits_location_service): If you implemented Visits Location Service then it will work for `background`, `foreground` and
> `terminate` state as well.

[image]

**Please refer below references.**

[Apple official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background)

[Raywenderlich article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: The note tells that disabling "Background App Refresh" does not prevent delivery of location events. It does not say anything about launching the app though. That's still up in the air.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the app terminated. If it is terminated by the user background fetching will not work (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666149)

Comment: This duplicates other answers and adds no new content, in fact providing much less. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an original answer by upvoting.

Comment: You just answer with the first comment in the forum thread, where the thread goes deeper. This is not a helpful answer.

Comment: You just answered the first answer in the thread, where the answer is actually more complex. This answer does not provide a helpful information to the requester.